# jQuery Sortable on table rows fail to move

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm trying to use the [jQuery Sortable](http://johnny.github.io/jquery-sortable/#table) code be able to allow the customer to sort their table rows. However, as is shown in this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/deu4enb7/1/), everything **except** the the dragging and dropping of rows occurs. I followed everything in the example on Sortable website, including checking the back end code, but it still seems to fail.

***The jQuery code***

```
$('.sorted_table').sortable({
    containerSelector: 'table',
    itemPath: '> tbody',
    itemSelector: 'tr',
    placeholder: '<tr class="placeholder"/>'
  });
```

---

***The CSS Code***

```
body.dragging, body.dragging * {
    cursor: move !important;
}
.dragged {
    position: absolute;
    opacity: 0.5;
    z-index: 2000;
}
.sorted_table tr {
    cursor: pointer;
}
.sorted_table tr.placeholder {
    display: block;
    background: red;
    position: relative;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    border: none;
}
.sorted_table tr.placeholder:before {
    content:"";
    position: absolute;
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    border: 5px solid transparent;
    border-left-color: red;
    margin-top: -5px;
    left: -5px;
    border-right: none;
}
```

---

Comment: You haven't included the jQuery library in your JSFiddle. Could that be the problem? https://jsfiddle.net/deu4enb7/3/

Comment: what's the expected behaviour?

Comment: @showdev Well...yes...yes it was.

Comment: @showdev Write up a dirty answer, I'll give you the points.

Comment: Your fiddle is throwing "Unexpected end of Input".   Syntax problem.

Comment: It's been resolved by @showdev, I'm just waiting for him to whip up an answer for credit.

Comment: @Trasiva I appreciate your considration, but I think this question is better closed as "a problem that can no longer be reproduced or a simple typographical error". If anyone disagrees, please explain your rationale.

Comment: @showdev Ah, yes. That makes sense in this case. Let the powers that be do so!

Answer (score 0):

This question needs closed, but it was a luser error, failing to include jQuery into the JSFiddle library.